# How to add a random google image search to a discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having problems with discord.js and I did it right 2 hours ago, but i tried to add another image search to it and now I can not get it back to the way it was. I tried reorganizing the little block code, the brackets, parenthisis and semicolons, I even tried undoing my changes in Visual Studio.

```js
     switch(args[0]) {
             case 'iDog':
               image(msg);
               break;
           }
           //emoji commands
           switch(args[0]) {
             case 'eYOUTUBE':
               if(args[1] === 'emoji') {
                 msg.react('668632526641692680')
               } else {
                 msg.reply('You must specify either 5 things'); //I'll decide the things later or learn how to react with a uploaded emoji
               }
             break;
             case 'eTWITTER':
              if(args[1] === 'emoji') {
                msg.react('668632550742163457')
              } else {
                msg.reply('You must specify either 5 things'); //I'll decide the things later or learn how to react with a uploaded emoji
              }
              break;
              case 'eINSTAGRAM':
              if(args[1] === 'emoji') {
                msg.react('668632483176120331')
              } else {
                msg.reply('You must specify either 5 things'); //I'll decide the things later or learn how to react with a uploaded emoji
              }
              break;
              case 'eREDDIT':
              if(args[1] === 'emoji') {
                msg.react('668632612897685524')
              } else {
                msg.reply('You must specify either 5 things'); //I'll decide the things later or learn how to react with a uploaded emoji
              }
              break;
              case 'eMEDIAMANIAC':
                if(args[1] === 'emoji') {
                  msg.react('668632652437389312')
                } else {
                  msg.reply('You must specify either 5 things'); //I'll decide the things later or learn how to react with a uploaded emoji
                }
           }



            switch(args[0]){
                case 'FACEBOOK':
                         if(args[1] === 'PROF'){
                          msg.reply('PLEASE TYPE PROF. NAME');  
                        }else{
                         msg.reply('ERROR, please type FACEBOOK followed by PROF');
                       }
                    break;            
                case 'INSTAGRAM':
                         if(args[1] === 'PROF'){
                          msg.reply('PLEASE TYPE PROF. NAME');  
                        }else{
                          msg.reply('ERROR, please type INSTAGRAM followed by PROF');
                       }
                   break;           
                case 'TWITTER':          
                         if(args[1] === 'PROF'){
                          msg.reply('PLEASE TYPE PROF. NAME');  
                        }else{
                          msg.reply('ERROR, please type TWITTER followed by PROF');
                        }
                        break;
                case 'REDDIT':
                        if(args[1] === 'PROF'){
                          msg.reply('PLEASE TYPE PROF. NAME');
                        }else{
                          msg.reply('ERROR, PLEASE TYPE REDDIT FOLLOWED BY PROF');
                        }
                        break;



                        case 'clear':
                          if(!args[1]) {
                            msg.reply('ERROR')
                          } else {
                            msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
                          }
                          var clear = msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
                          msg,channel.send('You have cleared' + clear + 'messages!');
                          break;


                        }

     })


     function iDog(msg) {

      var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "dog",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"
           }

        };

        request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
          if (error) {
              return;
          }


          $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);


          var links = $(".image a.link");

          var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

          console.log(urls);

          if (!urls.length) {

              return;
          }

          // Send result
          msg.channel.send( urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
      });


     }


    //bot uses the token ID to login
    bot.login(token);
```

If I do `function image(msg)` located near the bottom nothing pops up when I type in discord, because I obviously have to do `function iDog(msg)` but when i do that, the text gets slightly darker and when I hover over it, it says "iDog is declared, but it is never read" and I receive the error "image is not defined" in my terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing from

```
function iDog(msg) {
```

to

```
function image(message) {
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.